# roomba package for irobot create , compatible or not?

Tags: ros, roomba, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have installed ROS and studying the tutorials now. I have a Roomba from 4 o 5 years ago and it is the first generation roomba, probabaly the 400 serie.

I am thinking of  trying some roomba related stacks/package. I found this
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Roomba
which seems the best choice for my purpose.

It seems this package is for the roomba 500 series. I am not sure if it works with my old roomba 400 series. Also I have iRobot create from 3 years ago. Will this roomba package works for Create as well.

Anyone has first hand experience using the abovementioned Roomba package?

Thank you
Jack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43814/roomba-package-for-irobot-create-,-compatible-or-not?/) by [Jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3171/jackie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I´m trying to do the same, I´ve a Roomba Discovery, Arduino Mega, HS-SR04 x 4 and an XBOX360 Kinect. Putting tougher the hardware on top of a netboox Eee 1005PE running with Ubuntu 64bit with tourltebot 1 ROS (I hope).

The idea is to use ROS for images / audio  navigation processing, well experiment a little on what is possible to do.. the hardware would work as following:

- The roomba is interface via SCI port, the Arduino will manage he ultrasonic sensors that perform better then laser sensors on dark rooms.
- Kinect stack for Audio / Video.
- Idea is to combine both above for the navigation stack.

if will pass the phase one here describe.. and it is a little difficult.. will post the results.. The first problem I´ve is that I don´t like to run ubuntu on virtual box on my mac.. I would use the mac to develop / modify the nodes but so far no big progress.

I´ll keep you inform and maybe, if somebody else will replay to this discussion would be nice.

Regards,
Sandro

---

Originally posted by [SandroCA75](https://answers.ros.org/users/21862/sandroca75/) with karma: 16 on 2015-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0